# what % of intl should be in China equity mutual funds right now?

Tags: stocks, mutual-funds, investing, china

Mutual funds investing in China equity seem to be the strongest growing Intl equity mutual funds.

What percentage of my international equity mutual funds should I move to China equity mutual funds ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very personal and all depends on your personal risk appetite. No one can or should tell you what to do here. It all depends on how comfortable are you with the statement you made in your question and what your prediction is of the future of this market.

It also comes down to your analysis and research of the situation. Did you do the analysis and research yourself or are you following what you are reading elsewhere? If it is the latter I would be very careful.